# Offset edges along a plane

Tags: edges

How do you offset a series of edges evenly, looped or not?
Searching on line I came across 
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges which seems to be what I'm looking for but I can not get it to work using Blender v2.75.  Does something have to be done to activate this?  When I highlight an edge loop and hit Ctrl-E the pop-up menu does not include an 'Offset Edge' submenu.

I see this question has been asked before but the answers seem to refer to files that are no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using 2.76 And it all works just fine. Here are the steps:

You need to install the addon

1. Download the Add-on from the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bombaba/BlenderPythonScripts/master/mesh_offset_edges.py) in this page: https://github.com/Bombaba/BlenderPythonScripts/blob/master/mesh_offset_edges.py

[image]

2. To install the Add-on in Blender:

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> to open the User Preferences window. Go to the Add-ons Tab and press on Install from File:

[image]

Select the file you had downloaded earlier and click on istall from file

[image]

Back on the User preferences window find the Mesh section and enable Mesh:Offset Edges by clicking on the box on the right.

To make the add-on permanent on your blender installation press the Save User Settings button.

[image]

The add-on is now available and ready for use.

3. Select the object you want to work on and enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
4. Select the edges you want to affect and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>. The offset Edges option should be available in the Edges Menu.

[image]

5. The options for the tool will be displayed on the Toolshelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) or by pressing <kbd>F^</kbd>

[image]

Comment: The link in 1 leads to a text file.  Not sure how to install it.

Comment: The text file is the addon. It's a script in python language...

Comment: And I turn that into something Blender can use under Windows 7... how?  I know nothing about programming.

Comment: No need to learn programming or black magic or secret spells. Just save the file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bombaba/BlenderPythonScripts/master/mesh_offset_edges.py to your computer. It should be named mesh_offset_edges.py then just follow the instructions on the answer.

Comment: right click on the link and select "save as"

Comment: @Rivercoon see edited answer,