# How to cut along the edge of an object?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges

How do I cut a free form object (curve converted to mesh) along the edge?

[image: Blender screenshot with outline of new object.]

The goal is to create the smaller (blue outline) object, which looks like it has been sawn off the original one using a defined offset.

Comment: You could do this with the inset operator, but this reeks of bad topology see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35205/offset-for-mesh

Comment: Instead of converting the curve to mesh, keep it as curve and add some bevel.

Comment: If you convert that outline to mesh edges you can knife project it, then loop select the outer ring of verts and delete them

Comment: I used the Inset tool and fixed all the wrong edges etc.
Thank you very much